# Java-Module using Android API with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am currently migrating an Android project from classic IntelliJ IDEA format to Gradle. In my project, there are modules that are using the Android SDK without being Android modules. They are plain Java modules that use the Android SDK instead of a JDK.

How can I achieve that with Gradle?

The approach I can think of is to `apply plugin: 'java'` and somehow configure the Android SDK as the used JDK or as a dependency. But I don't know how to do it exactly...

Comment: There are some examples on GitHub for java projects:
https://github.com/lolay/investigo-android/blob/392a91fa5cd66b48a7ba568d061430ec9886ea2c/build.gradle

Comment: Sounds promising! That might be the solution. I'll get back as soon as I can test it.

Comment: That didn't do the trick. :/

Comment: Android API classes like `android.util.Log` are still not found. Currently I have switched to a different task.

Comment: Strange, since it should find them http://mavenhub.com/c/android/util/Log/jar

Answer (score 0):

I have just revisited Eugen's first hint and "suddenly" it works.

So, basically you need to apply the Java plugin and add Android as a provided dependency.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

configurations {
    provided
}

dependencies {
    provided 'com.google.android:android:2.2.1'
}
```

@Eugen: Maybe you'd like to repost this to receive your credits.